# Usename Ldapsearch on Active Directory where AD Domain is different from email domain

Tags: active-directory, ldap, postfix-mta, ldap-query

I am using Ldap in Debian 11 to authenticate users for Postfix against MS Active Directory with domain mandala.com. The request uses the user's email edmond@example.com to search with this script:

```
<code>

    server_host = 192.168.2.3
    search_base = dc=example,dc=com
    version = 3
    bind = yes
    start_tls       = no
    bind_dn         = vmail
    bind_pw         =  mypass
    scope           = sub
    query_filter    = (&(objectclass=person)(userPrincipalName=%s))
    result_attribute= userPrincipalName
    result_format   = %d/%u/Maildir/
    debuglevel      = 1
</code>
```

The problem is that Postfix uses the user's email edmond@example.com while on the Ad the user is edmond@mandala.com, hence the recipient cannot be found.

if I run an ldapsearch on the command line using dc=mandala, dc=com the user is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it passing the mail attribute

```
<code>

    query_filter = (&(objectclass=person)(mail=%s))
    result_attribute= mail

<code>
```